# SQLAlchemy can't adapt type "builtin_function_or_method"

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using Celery with Flask and SQLAlchemy to store some strings into the database. Everything works fine but when I created the database class:

```
class Locations(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.String(50))

def insert():
    location="Madrid"
    l = Locations(id=id, data=location)
    db.session.add(l)
    db.session.commit()
```

And when I access a url page is invokes the method insert(), I get this error, which I assume has something to do with id:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'builtin_function_or_method' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO locations (id, data) VALUES (%(id)s, %(data)s)'] [parameters: {'id': <built-in function id>, 'data': 'Oslo'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: Where does the id comes from in your insert() method ? if "from nowhere" then there IS an id method built into python and this is the one you are trying to use ... and you forget parenthesis and argument of id() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of type 'id' and 'data' and everything should work as expected.

```
class Locations(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(50))

def insert():
    location="Madrid"
    l = Locations(id=id, data=location) # You may want to remove id as well here as it will be autoincrement by default. 
   # So it can be l=Locations(data=location)
    db.session.add(l)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: thanks, that is strange. Last time I've look at the docs it required those fields.