# Unable to Insert New Records via Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I receive the following error when I try to insert a new row into a table via flask sqlalchemy. I only see this error when trying to insert a new row. I can query existing rows without issue.

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'builtin_function_or_method' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO beaches (id, beach_name, lat, long, beach_description) VALUES (%(id)s, %(beach_name)s, %(lat)s, %(long)s, %(beach_description)s)'] [parameters: {'lat': 45.01, 'beach_description': 'some stuff here', 'id': <built-in function id>, 'long': 45.01, 'beach_name': 'test'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

This is the code where I define the "beach" class in my models file.

```
class Beach(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'beaches'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    beach_name = db.Column(db.String(256))
    lat = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    long = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    beach_description = db.Column(db.String(256))

    def __init__(self, id, beach_name, lat, long, beach_description):
        self.id = id
        self.beach_name = beach_name
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.beach_description = beach_description
```

This is the code where I create the instance of the class and try to insert into the db.

```
beach_name = "test"
lat = 45.01
long = 45.01
beach_description = "some stuff here"

new_beach = Beach(id, beach_name, lat, long, beach_description)

db.session.add(new_beach)
db.session.commit()
```

This is the schema for the table that I am trying to insert into. I am using Postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE beaches (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    beach_name text,
    lat double precision,
    long double precision,
    beach_description text
);
```

There is a s[imilar-looking post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251809/sqlalchemy-cant-adapt-type-builtin-function-or-method) where a commenter suggests removing the "id" when creating an instance of the class. For me that would look like the code below. I have tried this variation, and I get the same error.

```
beach_name = "test"
lat = 45.01
long = 45.01
beach_description = "some stuff here"

new_beach = Beach(beach_name, lat, long, beach_description)

db.session.add(new_beach)
db.session.commit()
```

Even though the above recommendation does not work, I suggest the problem is somewhere with the auto-incrementing id column in my table. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody runs into a similar problem...

The solution is to remove 'id' from the list of arguments and the `self.id = id` bit from the Beach class, and to remove 'id' when creating a new instance of the Beach class.

I guess that since the beaches table is configured to auto-increment id when a new record is added (via the serial data type), it's not necessary to supply id when creating a new instance of the class.

The revised code for the class looks like this.

```
class Beach(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'beaches'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    beach_name = db.Column(db.String(256))
    lat = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    long = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    beach_description = db.Column(db.String(256))

    def __init__(self, beach_name, lat, long, beach_description):
        self.beach_name = beach_name
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.beach_description = beach_description
```

When creating the new instance and adding it to the db, it should look like this...

```
beach_name = "test"
lat = 45.01
long = 45.01
beach_description = "some stuff here"

new_beach = Beach(beach_name, lat, long, beach_description)

db.session.add(new_beach)
db.session.commit()
```